# Failed to find file with open source library (in VS2005), slash and backslash

Tags: visual-studio-2005, include-path

I try to include an opensource library for instance log4cpp but i am facing to an include problem. VS2005 cannot open files quoted like:
`<log4cplus/config.hxx>` !
But I've tried to replace the slashes with backslashed like: "log4cplus\config.hxx" and successfully it works. 
So this is certainly releated to VS project settings. Does anyone knows what option I have to change in the project as I don't want to modify the includes this library?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the parent directory of `log4cplus` to the `Additional Include Directories` property of your C++ project.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx) for the `/I` compiler option explains how to do that.